# Unclean shutdown breaks Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

My team has observed that if broker process die unclean then it will block producer from sending messages to kafka topic.

Here is how to reproduce the problem:
1) Create a Kafka 0.10 with three brokers (A, B and C).
2) Create topic with replication_factor = 2
3) Set producer to send messages with "acks=all" meaning all replicas must be created before able to proceed next message.
3) Force IEM (IBM Endpoint Manager) to send patch to broker A and force server to reboot after patches installed.

Note: min.insync.replicas = 1

Result:
- Producers are not able send messages to kafka topic after broker rebooted and come back to join cluster with following error messages.
[2016-09-28 09:32:41,823] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 0 : {logstash=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

We suspected that number of replication_factor (2) is not sufficient to our kafka environment but really need an explanation on what happen when broker facing unclean shutdown. The same issue occurred when setting cluster with 2 brokers and replication_factor = 1.

The workaround i used to recover service is to cleanup both kafka topic log file and zookeeper data (rmr /brokers/topics/XXX and  rmr /consumers/XXX).

Thanks,
Anukool

Comment: How do you set 'bootstrap.servers' in your code? Did you specify all the brokers in the list?

Comment: Yes, we did specific all brokers i.e. A:9092,B:9092,C:9092.

Comment: could you execute 'kafka-topics.sh' which describes the topic to see if there exists the leader for that partition before producing any messages to Kafka?

Comment: @amethystic here is a described topic.

Topic:logstash  PartitionCount:3        ReplicationFactor:2     Configs:
        Topic: logstash Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,3   Isr: 1,3
        Topic: logstash Partition: 1    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,1   Isr: 2,1
        Topic: logstash Partition: 2    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,2   Isr: 2,3

Comment: so could you retry to produce any messages to see if it can be successful? LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE means the Kafka controller does not contain the leader information in its cache. Machine A might be the controller, after it crashed, the controller failed over and the new controller's cache does not include leader information. As this time, the producer would fail to find the leader. Normally this should be transient, so that's why this is a WARNing not an ERROR